# ListBox showing one property in different rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am using the following code for binding ListBox to a list i.e. List and set the binding Path=Name. But the list box shows just the one name with letter divided in rows. Like if a Name is JOHN, the list box row 1 shows "J", row 2 shows "O", row 3 shows "H", row 4 shows "N". Here's the code.

**Xaml**

```
<ListBox Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,80,0,0" Name="ledgerListView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" KeyDown="ledgerListView_KeyDown" MouseDoubleClick="ledgerListView_MouseDoubleClick" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

**Code-Behind**

```
List<Ledgers> ledgers = new List<Ledgers>();
        ledgers = DAL_Ledgers.LoadLedgers();
        this.DataContext = ledgers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ItemsSource property needs to be bound to the source collection that you want to generate the list box's items from. In this case that would just be the DataContext. To show the name for each item you can either apply a DataTemplate to the ItemTemplate property containing what you want to show for each item, or for a simple case like this just use the DisplayMemberPath to specify the Name property.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" x:Name="ledgerListView"/>
```

Comment: Your solution is just working fine for other than the one problem. I am performing a search code for filter purposes which doesn't work. Here is code :

`List<Ledgers> ledgers = new List<Ledgers>();
            ledgers = DAL_Ledgers.LoadLedgers();
            this.DataContext = ledgers;
            ICollectionView view =
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ledgers);

            new TextSearchFilter(view, this.searchTextBox);`

Comment: You should create a new question with more details if you're having a separate problem with filtering.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're binding to the wrong thing... Does it work if you use:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to use an ObservableList, otherwise changes in ledgers won't be taken into account.